# I can not get environment at custom target shell

Tags: cmake

I can not get environment at custom target shell.

CMakeList.txt

```
set( ENV{TEST_VAR} "Hello" )
add_custom_target( test 
    COMMAND ./test.sh
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}  )
```

test.sh

```
echo test:${TEST_VAR}
```

when try to "make test", shell can't get ${TEST_VAR}.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a trick because environment variables SET in the CMakeLists.txt only take effect for cmake itself, so you cannot use this method to set an environment variable that a custom command might need:

test.cmake

```
set( ENV{TEST_VAR} "Hello" )
execute_process(
    COMMAND ./test.sh
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}  )
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_target( test
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P test.cmake )
```